# What sorts of problems does asymptotically safe gravity face as a potential quantum gravity solution?

Tags: gravity, particle-physics, string-theory, quantum-gravity, grand-unification

I've recently [read an article](http://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2015/12/17/what-are-quantum-gravitys-alternatives-to-string-theory/) by Ethan Siegel over at Forbes (he also blogs at Starts with a Bang) on asymptotically safe gravity as a possible alternative to string theory. I read the author's blog from time to time, and he's described the potential benefits of asymptotically safe gravity, as well as the apparent prediction of a 126 GeV Higgs Boson years ago.

My question is, what sorts of challenges does this idea face when it comes to quantum gravity? I feel like the buzz generated by an extremely accurate Higgs prediction, coupled with the ability to avoid adding entities like extra dimensions and supersymmetric particles, would be a huge positive in favor of asymptotically safe gravity. That being said, I do see much written on the subject and I wonder if that might be related to inherent problems or skepticism in relation to the framework.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, publication date, etc. of article, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for recommending that, added a bit more information just in case

Comment: Asymptotical safety of GR is a hypothesis (not a theory) for which there is currently still no proof. Sounds like a major problem.